# Picking a certain ID with Retrofit

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to filter a particular title by querying the URL's code. But I do not know how to work with it. I tried with these 2 examples and it did not work. Can someone help me?

```html
public interface PokemonService {
    @GET("app.php?acao=perfil&id={id}")
    public Call<Perfil> busca(@Path("id") int id);

}

or

public interface PokemonService {
    @GET("app.php?acao=perfil&id={id}")
    public Call<Perfil> busca(@Query("id") int id);

}
```

Comment: question is not clear please be more descriptive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public interface PokemonService {
@GET("app.php?acao=perfil")
public Call<Perfil> busca(@Query("id") int id);

}
```

use this

Comment: But how would I identify the part &id= ?

Comment: yea that looks fine did you updated the interface method as i told you ? isn't it working now?

Comment: I'm still going to do it. I'll test and I'll let you know.

Comment: Erro: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: its because your Perfil POJO class doesnt match with the jsonobject that you are receiving from server

Answer (score 1):

```
 public interface PokemonService {
   @GET("app.php?acao=perfil") 
   public Call<Perfil> busca(@Query("id") int id)
 }
```

And also check your model. it will be work fine this code

Comment: Erro: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Please change like this your Call method:-  public Call<List<Perfil>>busca(@Query("id") int id);.   I think your response is start from a array

Answer (score 0):

Try it for the error that you have

```
public interface PokemonService {
@GET("app.php?acao=perfil")
public Call<List<Perfil>> busca(@Query("id") int id);

}
```